# node js express not able to resolve node modules/merge-descriptors

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have a simple node.js express application.

When I run `npm run serve`, I am getting below error.

In my `node_modules` folders I can see `merge-descriptors` folder, but when I try to start `express server`, looks like it is complaining about not able to find the component.

My path correctly has `node_modules/.bin` set.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
throw err;
^
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'merge-descriptors'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object. (/tmp/site/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:16:13)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you importing the package in question yourself? If so, can you post a snippet of the code that imports it?

Comment: this might sound basic, but are you sure you haven't forgot to run `npm install` in your project's root folder?

Comment: yeah I did ran `npm install`